# Writing a vector with geopandas to MySQL is written as TEXT not as POLYGON

Tags: python, vector, geopandas, mysql

I am currently trying to write some vector files into a MySQL database. It works great for most vector files, but for some I got the eror:

`(pymysql.err.DataError) (1406, "Data too long for column 'geometry' at row 317")`
Yeah the row is different for different files.^^

The minimal code is:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import DataError
from geopandas import read_file
from pathlib import Path
from tqdm import tqdm



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_paths = {...}

    mysql = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://USER:PW$@localhost:3306/SCHEME")
    for name, main_path in main_paths.items():
        for path in tqdm(list(main_path.iterdir()), desc=f'In {name}'):
            gdf = read_file(path)
            gdf['geometry'] = gdf.buffer(0)


            try:
                gdf.to_sql(f'{name}'.lower(), mysql, if_exists='replace')
            except DataError as e:
                print(f"{e} in {name}.")
```

Turns out the geometry is written as text not as geometry! Is there a way to change that? The documentation states, that there are geometry types for MySQL.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify the CREATE TABLE syntax to create the table.

Comment: I am not sure whether it answers the question I tried to add the dtype parameter for the to_sql method: `dtype={'geometry': Geometry(geometry_type='POLYGON', srid=25833)})` or `dtype={'geometry': TEXT})`... The later returns the old error the new one returns `pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(POLYGON,25833)\n)' at line 28")`

Comment: Are you sure your geometry column is dtype geometry and not a text column?

Comment: UPDATE: in the DataFrame it's a geometry, I currently write it into the Database as LARGETEXT and CONVERT LARGETEXT -> GEOMETRY in the DB itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are geometry types in MySQL, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way with either `sqlalchemy` or `geoalchemy2` to specify the `dtype` (like you did in your comment) in such a way that it produces a valid statement with a geometry type column for MySQL. [This only seems to be possible for PostGIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361336/write-geodataframe-into-sql-database).

A workaround is exactly what you are doing now: [Import a WKT representation of the data as text first and then convert it to a geometry type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69569730/14015737).

If you experience the error that the text representations of your geometries are too large for a `TEXT` column in the first place , you can explicitly use the `dtype` parameter to store them in a `LONGTEXT` column. Then create a `GEOMETRY` type column and convert the `LONGTEXT` data.

In case you experience issues with encoding, you may need to [set the encoding first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69569730/14015737).

Full working example (that includes changing the db encoding):

```
import geopandas as gpd, sql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import LONGTEXT

mysql = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://USER:PW$@localhost:3306/dbscheme")

gdf = read_file('yourfilepath')
gdf = gdf.to_wkt()

with mysql.connect() as con:
    con.execute(sql.text("""ALTER DATABASE dbscheme CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;"""))

    gdf.to_sql('tablename', con, if_exists='replace', dtype = {'geometry': LONGTEXT})

    con.execute(sql.text("""ALTER TABLE dbscheme.tablename ADD COLUMN new_geometry GEOMETRY;"""))
    con.execute(sql.text("""UPDATE dbscheme.tablename SET new_geometry = ST_GeomFromText(geometry);"""))
```

This gives you the data in the column `new_geometry` of type `GEOMETRY`. You may want to drop the `LONGTEXT` column afterwards.

---

Note: I used `LONGTEXT` as it's the biggest you get. Depending on the size of your geometries `MEDIUMTEXT` might suffice. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13932834/14015737